# Powershell: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '' Key being added: '' when update AD attributes

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

The following powershell script is supposed to update user attributes in Active Directory from a specified excel sheet. However I am getting errors and unsure why. Seems to be something to do with the hashing.

Here is the script that updates AD users from the specified excel sheet.

```
#Declare file path and sheet name
$credential=Get-Credential

[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'

$file = "filepath.xlsx"  
#Create an Excel.Application instance and open that file
$Excelobject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excelobject.Workbooks.Open($file) 
$sheetName = "Sheet1" 
$sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
#$objExcel.Visible=$true 

#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
#Count max column
$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count
$hash = @{}
$server = "127.0.0.1"

#Specify starting positions
$row,$col = 1,1
$updatedCount = 0

#loop for rows 
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{

    #loop for columns
    for($c=0; $c -le $colMax-1; $c++)
    {
      #Get all columns values to a hash
      $hash += @{$sheet.Cells.Item($row,$col+$c).text =  $sheet.Cells.Item($row+$i,$col+$c).text}

    }

   #Create an object and assign hash keys as object property
   $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash

   #Get User via SamAccountname  
   $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Object.UserName)'" -Server $server -Credential $credential

   #Set Users attribute with matched object attribute
   $user | Set-ADUser -Title $Object.Title `
              -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $Object.Office `
              -Description $Object.Description `

              # -DisplayName $Object.Displayname `

   #If you want to edit Object common name, you can remove enable two lines below.

   #$userguid = $user.ObjectGUID.Guid
   #$user | Rename-ADObject -NewName $Object.DisplayName -Server $server -Credential $credential

   $hash = @{}
   Write-Host $User.Name "- User attributes have been updated." -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Start-Sleep -s 1
   $updatedCount += 1

}

Write-Host $updatedCount "Users have been updated" -ForegroundColor Green

#close excel file
$Excelobject.quit()
```

Here is the list of errors that I get when I run the scrip

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ''  Key being added: ''
At filepath.ps1:45 char:7
+       $hash += @{$sheet.Cells.Item($row,$col+$c).text =  $sheet.Cells ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ''  Key being added: ''
At filepath.ps1:45 char:7
+       $hash += @{$sheet.Cells.Item($row,$col+$c).text =  $sheet.Cells ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

New-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At filepath.ps1:51 char:14
+    $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand


Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName'.
At filepath.ps1:58 char:15
+               -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $Object.Office `
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: that 1st error message usually means exactly what it says. you have already added something with that exact key value to your hashtable. have you added diagnostic output to show you _exactly_ what the items are?

Comment: Adding to @Lee_Dailey 's comment: The first error message means you have duplicates in the `UserName` column in the Excel. The last error message shows that `Set-ADUser` doesn't use the LDAP attribute name `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` as parameter name. Instead, you need to use `-Office  $Object.Office`.

Comment: @Theo OK I think what it is doing is trying to add the empty rows in the excel sheet.

Comment: No, because you are using `+=` to add to the hashtable, you get this error if a key with that name already exists. If you don't care about that and want to overwrite the existing entry in such a case, you can use this syntax `$hash[$($sheet.Cells.Item($row,$col+$c).Text)] =  $sheet.Cells ...` , but I would **stongly** advise to double-check your imput Excel first **AND** add the `-WhatIf` switch to the Set-ADUser cmdlet while testing.

Comment: Also, I would recommend saving your Excel sheet (after de-duping) as CSV file, because that would make for much easier scripting without the hassle of (slow) reading from an Excel sheet.

Comment: Weird. I only have one entry in my sheet for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in my asp.net aspx page. I found the cause as below:

The Datakeynames field in any gridview header shows the fieldnames and their values you can access from code behind. The list of names added cannot have any duplicates. I had one field name duplicated in this list and the error was gone once it was removed.

I wish the error message said :  Duplicate Datakeynames - remove fieldname. Instead it talks about Powershell which cannot be directly related to Datakeynames.